# How to prove that a partial sum of the alternating harmonic series is less than a certain rational number

Tags: inequality

Question: How do we prove $\frac {1}{2}-\frac {1}{3}＋\frac {1}{4}-\frac {1}{5}+...－\frac {1}{999}＋\frac {1}{1000}\;<\frac {2}{5}$?

My progress:
$\frac {1}{2}-\frac {1}{3}＋\frac {1}{4}-\frac {1}{5}+...－\frac {1}{999}＋\frac {1}{1000}=\frac {1}{1000}＋\sum_{k＝1}^{499}\frac{1}{2k(2k＋1)}$.

How do I proceed.

Comment: [Choosing a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) is an important part of [asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/42969)

Comment: This series passes the Leibniz test for convergence.  It follows that the limit must lie between any two successive partial sums.

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain in another way?

Comment: $  \frac{1}{2}  -   \frac{1}{3} +    \frac{1}{4}  -   \frac{1}{5} +    \frac{1}{6}  <   \frac{2}{5}$

Comment: Read up on the [Leibniz test for Alternating Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).  When the  test applies (as here) you get a lot of information about the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your sum is
$$ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}  - \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} - \left( \frac{1}{7}  - \frac{1}{8} \right) - \left( \frac{1}{9}  - \frac{1}{10} \right) -\left( \frac{1}{11}  - \frac{1}{12} \right) - .........-\left( \frac{1}{999}  - \frac{1}{1000} \right)$$

Comment: Thank you for much .